# Can't access photo stored in SD Card from computer

Tags: sd-card

I have **Android 4.4.2**, and when i plug my phone in my pc, and try to access to my picture (i changed the settings to make it save the picture to my SD Card) from the folder: `Galaxy\Card\DCIM`, i dont see a thing, although when i go (in my phone) to **"My files"**, and select **"images"**, i can see all the images, and when i see the details, the path of the picture is `/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/Camera/2015....jpg`, but i cant even see the **"Camera"** folder in the pc.

UPDATE:
Even if browse to the `/storage/extSdCard/DCIM/` folder with the file manager app it's empty!

Comment: You're using MTP right? or PTP? What is the last folder you see in DCIM? Can you  see or read DCIM folder?

Comment: im using MTP (i even tried PTP) and the folder is just empty

Answer (score 0):

Most modern devices don't give you direct access to the sdcard from your computer. The "sdcard" is just an emulated storage area which can not be separately unmounted and provided to your computer via USB. 
They explained this sometime ago when it was introduced with 4.0? 4.1?

What you see on your computer is what the Android Media-Content-Provider knows.

In your case it's not up to date with the current content. To get it syncronized you will have to trigger a media scan.

See this question for how: [How do I refresh/rescan the SD memory in Android 4.4 KitKat](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/57913/how-do-i-refresh-rescan-the-sd-memory-in-android-4-4-kitkat)

If a normal media scan does not bring it into a consistent state:

There is a system app called similar to "Media storage" (packagename com.android.providers.media on a Nexus5), you can clear it's data and then do a media scan to start from a clean state.

Answer (score 0):

Newer Android versions have prevented this for a while by default but it is easy to change. When plugging in your phone using a USB cable there is a drop-down on the status bar with a few options. To see the card and navigate to it directly, select *Transfer Files* or something similar (It used to be labelled Mass-Storage Transfer).

This is working *right now* on my phone. Just mounted the device and it shows on the Desktop. Open it shows *Internal Shared Storage* plus the label of my *MicroSDXC Card*. Open that allows me to navigate and see all my images which are being stored on the card, just like with your setup.